# jQuery: Split words in string into smaller strings with limit

Tags: jquery, string

I got 2 address inputs with a max length of 40 (database can't be modified), and I want users to be able to type a long 40+ string and then split the string if it's longer than 40 characters and add the remaining **WORDS** into the next field. so something like this.

```
var Address = "This is a test address, split it, then this goes into the other input";
var Address1 = "This is a test address, split it, then";
var Address2 = "this goes into the other input';
```

So instead of slicing it, separate all the words that account for less than 40 characters and add the rest to the 2nd input.

I've been focusing the 2nd input on the limit but it acts exactly as a splice, this is what I currently have

```
$('#Address1').on('change keyup keydown', function()
{
    if($(this).length >= 40)
    {
        $('#Address1').focus();
    }
});
```

Comment: I actually had jQuery focus the 2nd input when the string is over 40, but that's the same as slicing and that's what I don't want

Comment: @Jofran Please add code that you've tried and describe what's not working. SO is not a forum to ask people to write your code for you.

Comment: So I add the code that I don't know? That's exactly why I asked, I don't need code, you can tell me "add a counter to a .split()" or something like that

Answer (score 0):

After some thinking and some donuts, I figured it out

```
$('input[name=Address1]').on('change', function()
{
    var i = "";
    var o = "";
    var u = "";
    var words = $(this).val().split(/ +/);
    $.each(words, function(index, value)
    {
        u += value + " ";
        if(u.length <= 40)
        {
            i += value + " ";
        }
        else
        {
            o += value + " ";
        }
    });
    i = i.replace(/\s*$/,"");
    o = o.replace(/\s*$/,"");
    $('input[name=Address1]').val(i);
    $('input[name=Address2]').val(o);
});
```